# Jailbreaking a locked iPhone 4s with iOS 6

Tags: jailbreak, iphone

I received an iPhone 4S as a gift, branded by Orange UK. It runs iOS 6 (6.0.1(10A523)).

I didn't unlock it yet; I'm using it without a SIM and I'm enjoying the apps, but I want to jailbreak it.

What should I do know? I want to use it locked, but is there a jailbreak?

Answer (score 6):

As of January 2013, there is no jailbreak for iOS 6. The reason is that iOS 6 introduced new security mechanisms and fixed the exploits that made the jailbreak possible on iOS 5.

You will have to wait.

Recent articles (December 2012):

- [Pod2g breaks silence on iOS 6 untethered jailbreak » Phone Reviews](http://www.phonesreview.co.uk/2012/12/21/pod2g-breaks-silence-on-ios-6-untethered-jailbreak/)
- [Hacker: jailbreaking iOS 6 hard, 6.1 may prove impossible | iPodNN](http://www.ipodnn.com/articles/12/12/24/forthcoming.update.adds.yet.more.resilient.code/)

Other good and curated jailbreaking news can be had at:

- http://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak (especially [this thread on 6.x jailbreaking](http://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/15yk8y/pod2g_returns_to_jailbreak_development_urges/c7r0yrb))
- https://twitter.com/planetbeing
- https://twitter.com/chpwn

Comment: +1 for some good information and links, but you're missing a bit so long as you don't restrict your answer to 4S-only. There are no *public untethered* jailbreaks for any devices on iOS 6 for now. However, the A4 devices are tethered (have to jailbreak again on each boot) for life, and the iPhone 3GS old bootrom is untethered (a "normal" jailbreak) for life.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Due to the topic, I've made my answer community wiki. Feel free to edit!

Comment: Found some good info here as well: http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/119673/jailbreaking-ios-6