# Is it possible to jailbreak an iPad 2 (A1395) after updating to iOS 6.0.1?

Tags: jailbreak, ios, ipad

I have a jailbroken iPad 2 (A1395) running Version 5.0.1 (9A405).

If I update to 6.0.1, can I jailbreak untethered?

Will I have to re-install all my Cydia apps & settings, or do they get backed up and restored?

Confused by too many Google results!

Comment: As of right now there is no untethered jailbreak available for iOS6. [See this question and answer.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76626/jailbreaking-a-locked-iphone-4s-with-ios-6)

Comment: Darn ... how about a tethered jailbreak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer true; Both answers were written before evasi0n came out. Now it's more than possible to JB 6.x devices, in fact up to 6.1.1/6.1.2.

As for backing up, you don't need to back up Cydia - it gets reinstalled anyway. What I would back up are any manually installed (i.e. hackulous-type) apps you may have (cd to /var/mobile/Applications, then do a tar)

Comment: So (1) back up /var/mobile/Applications; (2) then upgrade to ios6 via iTunes; (3) then apply evasi0n; and (4) restore those apps?

Answer (score 0):

Found some good info here as well:

http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/119673/jailbreaking-ios-6

Short answer: No.

Answer (score -1):

Dont do it!!!!!!!!!!!!!

If you upgrade you will kill any chance (at present of jailbreaking). 
I did mine last year without thinking and have regretted it ever since. stay with ios 5.1. Trust me there is no benefit at all in upgrading only losses